# how to call an XPath in a function

Tags: python, html

im trying to close down a popup on a webpage to webscrape it, ive tried many different things but the same "TypeError: 'str' is not callable" always pops up. now i understand that it thinks my xpath is a string, but ive found no help online on how to solve this.

```
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.fi.kayak.com/flights/HEL-ARN/2023-10-27/2023-10-29?sort=bestflight_a'

driver.get(url)
sleep(2)

#supposed way to find decline button for popup
popup_window = '/html/body/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'

#pressing decline button on popup
driver.find_element(By.XPATH(popup_window)).click()
```

replacing it with the class doesnt help either, and with my projects deadline fast approaching im dead in the water.